# yum install mysql-devel causing openssl11-devel conflicts with 1:openssl-devel-1.0.2k-24.amzn2.0.10.x86_64

Tags: mysql, yum, amazon-linux-2

I am tring to install RMysql Package however it throughs below error - which says mysql libraries are not installed.

[image]

I tried installing them using the yum command but there is a conflict with openssl.

[image]

How can I fix this and install the mysql library please. I am new to linux and just trying many things.  Tried yum update, rpm installing client libraries from mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve the conflict by removing openssl-devel package by following command.

```
yum remove {package name}
```

Or you can use --skip-broken in the end of command, it will skip the conflicted package.

```
yum install mysql-devel --skip-broken
```

Comment: initially I tried uninstalling `openssl11-devel.x86_64 1:1.1.1g-12.amzn2.0.18`  but it did not get uninstalled before but got removed now.